# How to store the images and display the same on the screen using struts?

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I want to store the images and display the same on the screen using struts. Is it better to store the images in database or on the file system? I have more than 10,000 images.

Answer (score 0):

Storing images in the database as objects like blob or clob is generally not recommended as this will make the database size huge. You may get poor results while processing your resultsets. The better way to do this is have the images get stored in your file system and simply use its references in the databases which is efficient. Using a hash check on the uploaded images will also help in verifying the integrity of the images if they are uploaded to the server from the clients.

Answer (score -1):

File system. It turns out it's quite good at storing files.